# Constructor not defined Error for test case

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test

I have an error that seems common on the web,

Though i cant find a definite answer that applies to my case:

I have the following Apex code:

```
public with sharing class templicenseemail {
     private ApexPages.standardController standardController;

     public Trainee__c trainee { get; set; }
    public templicenseemail(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.standardController = standardController;
    }
     public PageReference doSomething()
    {

       trainee  = [SELECT Email__c,First_Name__c,Institution__c,Last_Name__c FROM Trainee__c 
                WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

                String whatIs = trainee.Volume_Serial_Number__c;
                integer strlen = whatIs.length();

                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, trainee.Email__c  ));
        return null;

    }   

}
```

And the following test case:

```
@isTest(seealldata=false)

    private class Send_noti_emailsTestClass5 {

        static testMethod void validateSend_noti_emails5() {

            templicenseemail  MyTestcase = new templicenseemail();

            // code here in the Middle

            MyTestcase.doSomething();

        }
    }
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Compile Error: Constructor not defined: [templicenseemail].<Constructor>(SOBJECT:Lead) at line:

    templicenseemail  MyTestcase = new templicenseemail();
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't calling the correct constructor.

From your class, the signature is `public templicenseemail(ApexPages.StandardController controller)` but in your test case you are trying to invoke `templicenseemail()`.

The solution is to first instantiate a StandardController and pass that as a parameter to your controller.

Sample:

```
static testMethod void MyTestMethod(){
  // Insert test data here
  Trainee_c myTestTrainee = [SELECT id From Trainee_c LIMIT 1];

  Test.startTest();

  PageReference myVfPage = Page.MyVisualforcePage;
  Test.setCurrentPage(myVfPage);
  ApexPAges.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(myTestTrainee);
  templicenseemail testController = new templicenseemail(sc);
  // Do something
  Test.stopTest();

  // Assertions to verify behaviour
}
```

Comment: So i understand now what my problem is, but i don't understand how the example in the link you are referring to applies to my situation!!

Comment: You're right; I've added sample code instead.

Comment: I have a different error now, can i ask it here or do i need to open another question?

Comment: I would recommend a different question; that will attract the most attention to help you.